# Windows 10 detect keyboard layout change

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, text-services-framework

I'm trying to implement a service that would monitor language/layout changes. I switch between English and Russian languages. So far I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872846/application-not-detecting-input-language-changes-via-text-service-framework-dll) and tried to implement and install both sinks suggested there.
However, there are problems. `ITfActiveLanguageProfileNotifySink::OnActivated` is not triggered at all; `ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink::OnLanguageChange` is not triggered, too; `ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink::OnLanguageChanged` is triggered only when the main window of my program is in foreground, but it doesn't contain any information on the language. Is there any way to monitor input language change event globally?

Comment: Does your app main window get the [`WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-inputlangchange)?

Comment: @AdrianMole no, unfortunately it doesn't. I think it might be because I have an edit box that fills the whole window and the message is sent to it instead of the main frame. Anyway, the message should be sent to the active window only, and I need to be able to react to input language changes even when my window is in the background.

Comment: OnActivated should we called, shouldn't it? Do you have any reproducing project?

Comment: @SimonMourier yes, here's the default VS2019 "desktop app" [project](https://github.com/sokolas/lang_change) with `ITfActiveLanguageProfileNotifySink` implementation that I took from [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/IME/cpp/SampleIME/ActiveLanguageProfileNotifySink.cpp)

Comment: I don't think this interface is for a Windows global language change, more for your application only, if that's what you're after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another way to detect such changes: to use [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) with `WH_SHELL`. One of the available event is `HSHELL_LANGUAGE` which is exactly what I need and the test project seems to work just fine.
There's [an article](https://sudonull.com/post/101942-Keyboard-layout-indicator-with-the-color-of-the-taskbar-and-window-title-in-modern-versions-of-Windo) by Alexander Shestakov that describes a program very similar to what I'm trying to achieve and it also has a link to github project that I use as an example.